# "super star" or find the word under the cursor equivalent in emacs

Tags: search, vim, emacs, editor

I'm a vim user and have recently been trying out emacs for fun.  I find that the feature I'm missing most so far from vim is the "[super star](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1)" (find the word under the cursor by typing *) feature, and I have yet to find the equivalent in emacs.  If it's not built in, what would I need to add to my emacs file to get something similar?

Comment: i didn't know about that in VIM. Cool :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589691/how-can-i-emulate-vims-search-in-gnu-emacs

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate, but it's easier to find for a vim user who knows the command as super star.  The other answer never mentions the word 'star' which made it hard for me to find.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As [pointed out](/questions/1775005/super-star-or-find-the-word-under-the-cursor-equivalent-in-emacs#comment54758673_1775184) by [paldepind](/users/556072/paldepind), `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` (<kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, by default) is a close equivalent to <kbd>*</kbd> in Vim. This function is available starting in GNU Emacs 24.4; if your Emacs is different or older, read on for alternatives.

Usually I just do (<kbd>M-b</kbd> ...) <kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>C-w</kbd> ... <kbd>C-s</kbd>. That is:

1. <kbd>M-b</kbd> to move to beginning of word(s) of interest

   - zero or more of these
2. <kbd>C-s</kbd> to start an I-Search
3. <kbd>C-w</kbd> to yank the word(s) starting at point

   - one or more of these
4. <kbd>C-s</kbd> to find the next match
5. more <kbd>C-s</kbd> to find later matches
6. <kbd>RET</kbd> to exit the I-search at the most recent match

   - or a bunch of <kbd>C-g</kbd> to abort back to the original starting location

Here is a go at integrating it into I-Search (invoked via <kbd>C-s</kbd> and <kbd>C-r</kbd>; use <kbd>C-h k</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> for info on `isearch`).

```
(require "thingatpt")
(require "isearch")
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-*")
  (lambda ()
    "Reset current isearch to a word-mode search of the word under point."
    (interactive)
    (setq isearch-word t
          isearch-string ""
          isearch-message "")
    (isearch-yank-string (word-at-point))))
```

Integrating it into I-Search takes advantage of its word matching and case sensitivity settings (<kbd>C-s</kbd> <kbd>M-c</kbd> <kbd>C-*</kbd> would do a case-sensitive search on the word under point).

Comment: Any way to put all this piano combination into some single keypress more like in vim ?

Comment: What about using `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` which by default is bound to `C-s .`

Comment: @paldepind: That looks nice; NEWS indicates that it originated in GNU Emacs 24.4 (October 2014).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Yes. It's somewhat recent. I think updating the answer would be great!

Answer (score 18):

Try <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd>

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. It assumes the point is at the start of the word while *super star* feature in Vim can be used from anywhere within the word.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a start:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-*")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (re-search-forward (format "\\b%s\\b" (thing-at-point 'word)))))
```

Answer (score 7):

These days there is also [Smart Scan](https://github.com/mickeynp/smart-scan), a lightweight add-on package that provides this functionality.

It is available from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/); instructions for adding MELPA to the list of enabled `package-archives` are [here](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started).

To install it:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `smartscan` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can then enable it via

```
(global-smartscan-mode t) ;; Turn on Smart Scan globally
```

The default key bindings for searching forward and backward are <kbd>M-n</kbd> and <kbd>M-p</kbd>, respectively.

---

PS: If you are interested, the original blog post introducing this package is [here](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/10/31/smart-scan-jump-symbols-buffer/).

Answer (score 4):

if you're using viper (which works great) this should work similarly enough:

```
(require 'thingatpt)
(require 'viper)

(defun viper-search-word-at-point ()
  "Reset viper-s-string to word at point and start a forward viper search."
    (interactive)
    (setq viper-s-string (word-at-point))
    (viper-search viper-s-string 't nil))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-*") 'viper-search-word-at-point)
```

Answer (score 4):

`C-s C-w` is ok but it's not strictly symbol search, but "word part at the right of point" search.

The correct answer is `M-s .` This starts [symbol search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Symbol-Search.html) with the symbol at point preloaded. Symbol search is a special mode of isearch that you can start with `M-s _`. If you're already in isearch (for example, after pressing `C-s` or `C-r`) you can also type `M-s _` to enter symbol search.

I urge you to read the entire documentation of isearch since it's very powerful and versatile.